# PHP : Order By Available Day and Available time

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table `student_availability` where there is two fields `available_day` type varchar and `available_time` type also varchar.

On table data inserted as below :

[image]

I want this data in order by `available_day` (ex : Sunday,Monday,Tuesday) and `available_time`.
(Ex : '07:00  - 08:00 AM','08:00  - 09:00 AM','09:00  - 10:00 AM','10:00  - 11:00 AM','11:00  - 12:00 PM') etc

I have tried with simple sql query  :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `student_availability`
ORDER BY `available_day` AND `available_time`


but its not giving accurate results.

PHP QUERY :

    Studentavailability::orderBy('available_day')->orderBy('available_time')->get();
```

Comment: That query should not even be running. Please check that you are showing us the REAL syntax

Comment: _but its not giving accurate results_ Is a bit too general!! What is it producing? And what is wrong with what it is producing

Comment: It would also appear you are using a Framework, its useful to tell us (or TAG) the one you are using

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanx for suggestions. I just want result in order like I mentioned, as I am not able to do any modification on existing table.

Comment: `order by available_day, available_time` an AND in there does odd things But that also wont do as you want

Comment: A useful read on how to get things [sorted in an specific way](https://electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/) Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It would have been better to store a `avail_from` and `avail_to` and both as DATETIME types. You could have then got all the info you currently have PLUS a whole lot more, and the sorting would have been easy

Comment: Thinks the laravel is wrong, you probably want `Studentavailability::orderBy('available_day, available_time')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `student_availability`
ORDER BY `available_day` **AND** `available_time`
```

This will order by available_day and check (?) available_time
If you want to sort by available_day and inside the result, sort also by available_time, you must write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `student_availability`
ORDER BY `available_day`, `available_time`
```